# How to expose an Objective-C Module properly using Bazel?

Tags: swift, build, bazel

I'm trying to build RxSwift using Bazel in order to be able to use it in a dummy project as a dependency, for the sake of getting to know it a bit.

We don't use the *latest* RxSwift version at the moment, but version 4.4.2.

After reading through the docs, I've come to the point where I successfully add the specific release to my workspace as an `http_archive`, and supply my own BUILD file to build that external dependency `RxSwift`.

You can check out the BUILD file and WORKSPACE file here: 
https://gist.github.com/daneov/487444109c703087862d830a3445ee86

Running

> bazel build @rx_swift//:RxSwift

yields a *Swift* compilation error:

> No such module: RxAtomic

So, this shows that my I'm missing something with regards to exposing the Objective-C module to a Swift library.
I currently supply these options to the `objc_framework`:

```
enable_modules = 1,
alwayslink = 1,
module_name = "RxAtomic"
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts/pointers!

Answer (score 0):

You should call `bazel build` with `--experimental_objc_enable_module_maps` option

Comment: The option doesn't exists: ```ERROR: --experimental_objc_enable_module_maps :: Unrecognized option: --experimental_objc_enable_module_maps```